# Can't mount ecrytpfs as a non-root user on Red Hat

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, disk-encryption, ecryptfs

I'm trying to mount a ecryptfs volume on Red Hat as a regular user. `ecryptfs-utils` is installed from source (repos only contain old versions). Mounting as root works normally, but trying with a regular user (who owns the mount) results in a `mount: no such file or directory`(descriptive, I know). This same procedure works flawlessly on Ubuntu, Debian and CentOS.

This is how I mount:
`ecryptfs-add-passphrase`
`mount -i /path/volume`

(`-i` is required for automounting. Without it, the ecryptfs mount helper is called which is interactive, i.e. requires user input.)

`fstab` is correctly set up, i did `chmod +s /sbin/mount.ecryptfs` as suggested by documentation but nothing helped. Note that mounting non-ecryptfs volumes with regular users works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid deleting and reposting your questions. Instead, edit the question.